# Tampermonkey: display an element if it's hidden (and vice versa)

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I would like to hide/show some div on Youtube based on a keyboard shortcut. I am able to hide the div but not to display them, once I have hidden them.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube enhanced
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Youtube enhanced
// @author       You
// @include     *youtube.com/watch*
// for change CSS
// @grant    GM_addStyle

// ==/UserScript==


window.addEventListener("keydown", dispatchkeyboard, false);

function dispatchkeyboard(key) {
    // frontcolor

    if (key.altKey && key.code === "KeyC") { // KeyX
        alert("c")
        var hidden_or_display = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-gradient-bottom")[0].style.display;
        alert(hidden_or_display)
        if (hidden_or_display == "none") {
            alert('none')
            var display = ".ytp-gradient-bottom,.ytp-gradient-top,.ytp-chrome-top,.ytp-chrome-bottom{display:block;}"
            var tag = document.createElement("style");
            tag.type = "text/css";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
            tag[(typeof document.body.style.WebkitAppearance == "string") ? "innerText" : "innerHTML"] = display
        } else {
            alert('else')
            var goaway = ".ytp-gradient-bottom,.ytp-gradient-top,.ytp-chrome-top,.ytp-chrome-bottom{display:none;}";
            var tagd = document.createElement("style");
            tagd.type = "text/css";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tagd);
            tagd[(typeof document.body.style.WebkitAppearance == "string") ? "innerText" : "innerHTML"] = goaway
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline style has a greater priority over style declared in stylesheet. Changing the style of an element via stylesheet won't change the inline style value.

I've not got tampermonkey installed so untested, change

```
  var hidden_or_display = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-gradient-bottom")[0].style.display;
```

to

```
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-gradient-bottom")[0];
  var hidden_or_display = element.style.display;

  // toggle inline style
  element.style.display = hidden_or_display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! For those interested, here is the full script: https://pastebin.com/NAVHn1mc